# Does p2p mean "Pay to Play" or "Peer to Peer"

Tags: terminology

Both terms are used often in the gaming world and people tend to use "p2p" for abbreviating both. What are the correct abbreviations and usages?

Peer to Peer generally means a multiplayer game that is hosted on one of the player's machines.

Pay to Play is obviously when you pay a fee to play a game, such as WoW.

Comment: Why can't it mean both?

Comment: strangely related: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/671/why-do-we-have-rpg-and-first-person-shooter

Answer (score 21):

This is a contextual acronym, and neither is incorrect nor misused. It's the same that `fps` stands for "First Person Shooter" when you are talking about game genre, and "Frames Per Second" when you are talking about framerates. You simply have to read which one is in use.

Generally, `p2p` for communication is more widely known because it is an older acronym used in a lot of contexts outside of electronic gaming. For payment, it is diametrically opposed to Free To Play, or `f2p`, and is a lot more exclusive to gaming. Note that if Pay To Play was `ptp`, that would entail a separate conflict with `ftp` as File Transfer Protocol, so it's not like there's a "nice" alternative.

Comment: +1 for the `fps` example

Comment: Or [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) / [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) / [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Source)

Comment: @BlueRaja: Cross-site Scripting is usually referred to as XSS.

Comment: @Powerlord:  Yes, I know - I have, however, heard it referred to as CSS from time to time, especially when discussing cross-site request forgery, which is confusingly labeled CSRF

Comment: @BlueRaja: Years ago, I had a very awkward conversation with a "security professional" who used CSS to mean both, sometimes in the same breath.  I shudder now that I remember it.

Comment: To quote @badp
`I'm so tempted to reply, Both. Use context. but that would be giving up in my fight to have the [fps] tag!`

Comment: @tzenes, @-mentions don't work on people who didn't take part in the post - I still see what you did there, though :)

Comment: Another one that has caused confusion for me during conversations several times:  [OSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) / [OSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Source_Initiative)